# How to setTimeout in node.js?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, blocking

I need to be able to make retries in `node.js` in the event of failure inside a function.  I've setup a while loop as shown below, but I am getting slightly confused about how I should wrap the function call to not make sure that it won't block my whole server.

What should I do?

```
while(retryCount < 10 && !success){

    // Alternative one
    while(new Date().getTime() < now + 1000) {
        myFunction();
    }

    // Or:
    setTimeout( myFunction(), 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store number of tryes in function object. It's will be fine for cronjob. If you need same behaviour in request context you must store attempts counter in request scope (not in function object).

```js
var fnc = function() {
        console.log('try');
        if (true) { // Error condition
                // Error here
                if (!fnc.tryes) fnc.tryes = 0;
                fnc.tryes++;
                console.log(fnc.tryes);
                if (fnc.tryes <= 10) {
                        setTimeout(fnc, 1000);
                } else {
                        fnc.tryes = 0;
                }
                // Something wrong
        } else {
                // We hame result
        }
};

fnc();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say use the setTimeout method, that way the client won't be stuck inside the while loop that checks the time.

Answer (score 0):

That outer while loop is going to block, you'd have to refactor using **only** setTimeout. However, the fact that you want this sort of thing indicates to me that your code structure is really terrible and needs more reworking. What is it that you are retrying? How are you detecting an error condition? Does doing it 10 times really make the chances of success higher?

I have a gist containing a generic function that will do this sort of thing for you, but I'm reluctant to share if this is an XY problem.

Comment: It's going to be used in a CRONjob that makes a HTTP request to a public API and pulls some data. In the case of a HTTP error, I would like to sleep the script for a while and try again a certain number of times

Comment: @Industrial https://gist.github.com/2106760. Modify to suit your desires. That is non-blocking, either add in error checking or copy the pattern. Any time you have a `while` loop, you are going to block.